# How to create a surface plot with matplotlib in python given a z function

Tags: python-3.x, matplotlib, 3d, surface

I have a function of z:

z = 0.4x + 0.7y + 0.8x^2 + 0.5xy + 0.2y^2

**(-3 < x <3, -3 < y <3)**

Is there a way to plot an illustrating 3d surface plot of x,y,z using matplotlib in python?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Sympy](https://docs.sympy.org), Python's symbolic math library, contains a function [`plot3d_parametric_surface`](https://docs.sympy.org/latest/modules/plotting.html). Sympy's plotting internally uses matplotlib. Note that Python uses `**` for powers, as `^` is reserved for `exclusive or`.

```py
from sympy.plotting.plot import plot3d_parametric_surface
from sympy.abc import x, y

plot3d_parametric_surface(x, y, 0.4 * x + 0.7 * y + 0.8 * x ** 2 + 0.5 * x * y + 0.2 * y ** 2, (x, -3, 3), (y, -3, 3))
```

[image: result]

PS: For a solution without sympy, matplotlib's [`plot_surface`](https://matplotlib.org/3.1.0/gallery/mplot3d/surface3d.html) can be called directly, for example via numpy's meshgrid. Note that sympy defaults to adaptively subdividing the ranges, adding more detail where the surface is more curved. With the meshgrid you'd get a fixed division of the parameter space.